# sql search function ignoring any results in database with null values VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have an issue with my vb web form. I have a search function with 5 textboxes, users type firstname + surname in textbox 1, dpeartment name in textbox 2, and so on.

The issue is that some of the database rows have null values, mostly the Pager collumn.

The search function will only return rows that have data in every collumn.

I beleive its something to do with the control parameters but cant work it out.

Here is my code

thanks

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnectionConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [FirstName], [Surname], [DepartmentName], [ExtensionName], [jobTitle], [Pager] FROM [UserInformation]"
    FilterExpression="[FirstName] + ' ' + [Surname] like '%{0}%' and [DepartmentName] like '%{1}%' and [ExtensionName] like '%{2}%' and [jobTitle] like '%{3}%' and [Pager] like '%{4}%'">

    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch1" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"  Name="FirstName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />

        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch2" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="DepartmentName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch3" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="ExtensionName" PropertyName="text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch4" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="jobTitle" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch5" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="Pager" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Is a stored procedure an option? You'd be able to conditionalize what to do when you have null values. (A blank passed from a control is probably not equal to a null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your SQL query to convert null values to empty fields. i.e., change this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnectionConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [FirstName], [Surname], [DepartmentName], [ExtensionName], [jobTitle], [Pager] FROM [UserInformation]"
```

Into this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconnectionConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT isnull([FirstName],'') [FirstName], isnull([Surname],'') [Surname], isnull([DepartmentName],'') [DepartmentName], isnull([ExtensionName],'') [ExtensionName], isnull([jobTitle],'') [jobTitle], isnull([Pager],'') [Pager] FROM [UserInformation]"
```

---

### But keep in mind...

The second parameter of the `isnull()` functions in the above example are all empty string values, which work great for strings, but if you have a smallint (maybe `[Pager]` perhaps?) then you may want to do something like `isnull([Pager],0)`.

### Additionally...

You may notice that I've included the field name a second time after the `isnull()` functions. This is because when you use a function to pull the field it will likely lose its field name. You can define field names by following them with a custom field name in brackets `[like_this]`.

Comment: i was just writing this answer when i got distracted. Yours was better than mine would have been though. Might be worth including the 'As' keyword just because it makes the use of the field name following the isnull function a bit clearer?

Comment: Thanks Lopsided, that worked great. Thanks for explaining the solution too!

Comment: @5uperdan tamaytoe tamahtoe. Thanks tho :)